# Making a switch function work properly

Tags: ios, swift, enums, switch-statement

I have two textfield that I intent to use as pickerviews, with corresponding input:

```
@IBOutlet weak var pickerCountry: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerAge: UITextField!

var pickOptionCountry = ["Belgium", "France", "Germany", "Netherlands", "Sweden"]
var pickOptionAge = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

I have created an Enum with the two possible textfields and a created an instance for the Enum:

```
enum optionsPicker {
    case pickerCountry
    case pickerAge}

var optionPicked = optionsPicker.pickerTextFieldCountry
```

In the viewDidLoad I've set up all the necessities for a pickerview to work, and it works fine for a single pickerview.

However, when I try to make the function dynamic using the following switch code (for simplicity I've left out the other functions for a pickerview), I only get the input for pickerCountry. Can anybody explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    switch optionPicked {
    case .pickerCountry:
        return pickOptionCountry[row]
    case .pickerAge:
        return pickOptionAge[row]
    }
}
```

It seems the switch function is not working properly, as I only get the input that I've declared in the optionPicked instance. Below is the viewDidLoad code for your reference:

```
let pickerView = UIPickerView()
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true
        pickerCountry.inputView = pickerView
    pickerCountry.placeholder = "Country Not Set"
        pickerAge.inputView = pickerView
    pickerAge.placeholder = "Age Not Set"
```

Comment: Where did you change picker Type ? so you change it at all? or do you want when user clicks on country text field you show countries ? and when he clicks on age text field you show age picker view ? and please show more code. viewdidload, and which delegate method of text field you are using.

Comment: Indeed I want to show countries when a user clicks on countries and age numbers when a user clicks on ages. I've added the viewDidLoad code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the problem now.

I think you do NOT need an enum for this case.

try

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView == self.countryPickerView {
        return pickOptionCountry[row]
    }else if pickerView == self.agePickerView{
        return pickOptionAge[row]
    }
    return nil
}
```

where self.countryPickerView and self.agePickerView are your picker views. I'm assuming here you're having them as properties.

EDIT:

add two properties just below your IBOutlets.

```
var countryPickerView = UIPickerView()
var agePickerView = UIPickerView()
```

and initialise them in your viewDidLoad()

I think you wanted to have one pickerView and reuse it ?

I think this would be tough. using two picker view will make your life a lot easier.